# Change Material Design TreeViewItem background color without changing Expander's color

Tags: wpf, xaml, material-design

Using Material Design, I'm building a WPF application which has a `TreeView`. When a `TreeViewItem` is selected, it is highlighted by its background switching to red and its foreground switching to white, for aesthetic reasons.

The problem is that when I change the foreground to white, it also changes the `Expander`'s color, therefore it switches to white and as my background is white as well, we can't see it anymore.

Is there any way to prevent the `Expander` from changing color, or any way of extending the background all the way to the `Expander`?

Here's what I have so far:

```xml
<Style TargetType="TreeViewItem" BasedOn="{StaticResource MaterialDesignTreeViewItem}">
    <Style.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="True">
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="White"/>
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="{DynamicResource Red}"/>
            <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="Medium"/>
        </Trigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
    <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="22"/>
</Style>
```

Unselected `TreeViewItem`:

[image: Unselected TreeViewItem]

Selected `TreeViewitem`, with the `Expander` going white:

[image: Selected TreeViewitem, with the expander going white]

Comment: A code snippet of what youv'e implemented would make this easier to answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can change the TreeViewItem's content foreground color independently to the expander's foreground by using an ItemTemplate.

Here's a quick example where the content is shown in red and the expander color remains unchanged (e.g. white)..

```
<TreeView DockPanel.Dock="Bottom" ItemsSource="{Binding HitGamesView}"
                  ItemTemplate="{StaticResource HitGamesItemTemplate}" />
...
<HierarchicalDataTemplate x:Key="HitGamesItemTemplate" DataType="game:GameDetail">
  <TextBlock Text="{Binding Game.Description}" Foreground="Red" />
</HierarchicalDataTemplate>
```

[image: example render]